# numba.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend) Type of variable 'argmax' cannot be determined

Tags: python, python-3.x, numba

I try to speed  up my python code by using `numba`. But after days of trying and hundreds of error messages, I still fail to get it work.

My current problem is this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Studium/Masterarbeit/Masterarbeit/code/fast_simulation.py", line 152, in <module>
    epsis, ks, vn, ln = monte_carlo(n, m, alpha, epsilon_max, delta, aufloesung, fehlerposition)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py", line 401, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py", line 344, in error_rewrite
    reraise(type(e), e, None)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\numba\six.py", line 668, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
numba.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Type of variable 'argmax' cannot be determined, operation: $300unpack_sequence.5, location: E:/Studium/Masterarbeit/Masterarbeit/code/fast_simulation.py (126)

File "fast_simulation.py", line 126:
def monte_carlo(n: int, m: int, alpha: float, epsilon_max: float, delta: float, aufloesung: int, x_position: float):
    <source elided>

            argmax, max_value = get_max_ks(random_values)
```

My code is

```py
@njit
def insort(a, x, lo=0, hi=None):
    """Insert item x in list a, and keep it sorted assuming a is sorted.
    If x is already in a, insert it to the right of the rightmost x.
    Optional args lo (default 0) and hi (default len(a)) bound the
    slice of a to be searched.
    """

    if lo < 0:
        raise ValueError('lo must be non-negative')
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(a)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        if x < a[mid]:
            hi = mid
        else:
            lo = mid+1
    a.insert(lo, x)

@njit
def get_max_ks(data: list) -> (float, float):
    def f(x, data):
        return sqrt(len(data)) * abs(np.searchsorted(data, x, side='right') / n - x)

    max_value = -1000
    argmax = 0.0
    epsilon = 1 / (n * 10 ** 6)
    for i in range(n):
        data_i = data[i]
        fx1 = f(data_i, data)
        fx2 = f(data_i + epsilon, data)
        fx3 = f(data_i - epsilon, data)
        if fx1 > max_value:
            max_value = fx1
            argmax = data_i
        if fx2 > max_value:
            max_value = fx2
            argmax = data_i + epsilon
        if fx3 > max_value:
            max_value = fx3
            argmax = data_i - epsilon
    return argmax, max_value

@njit
def get_max_vn(data: list) -> (float, float):
    def g(x, data):
        return sqrt(len(data)) * abs(np.searchsorted(data, x, side='right') / n - x) / sqrt(
            x * (1 - x))

    max_value = -1000
    argmax = 0.0
    epsilon = 1 / (n * 10 ** 6)
    for i in range(n):
        data_i = data[i]
        fx1 = g(data_i, data)
        fx2 = g(data_i + epsilon, data)
        fx3 = g(data_i - epsilon, data)
        if fx1 > max_value:
            max_value = fx1
            argmax = data_i
        if fx2 > max_value:
            max_value = fx2
            argmax = data_i + epsilon
        if fx3 > max_value:
            max_value = fx3
            argmax = data_i - epsilon
    return argmax, max_value


@njit
def get_critical_value_vn(alpha: float, n: int) -> float:
    loglogn = log(log(n))
    an = sqrt(2 * loglogn)
    dn = 2 * loglogn + 0.5 * log(loglogn) - 0.5 * log(pi)
    return (dn - log(-0.5 * log(1 - alpha))) / an


@njit
def monte_carlo(n: int, m: int, alpha: float, epsilon_max: float, delta: float, aufloesung: int, x_position: float):
    epsilons = np.linspace(min(0.0, epsilon_max), max(0.0, epsilon_max), aufloesung)
    res_ks = np.zeros(n)
    res_vn = np.zeros(n)
    res_ln = np.zeros(n)
    ks_critical_value = 1.2238478702170836  # TODO
    vn_critical_value = get_critical_value_vn(alpha, n)
    ln_critical_value = 2.7490859400901955  # TODO

    for epsilon in epsilons:
        for i in range(m):
            uniform_distributed_values = np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.0, n)
            random_values = []
            for x in uniform_distributed_values:
                if x < max(0, x_position - delta) or x > min(1, x_position + delta):
                    insort(random_values, x)
                elif max(0, x_position - delta) <= x and x <= x_position + epsilon:
                    insort(random_values,
                                  (x - x_position - epsilon) / (1 + (epsilon / min(delta, x_position))) + x_position)
                else:
                    insort(random_values,
                                  (x - x_position - epsilon) / (
                                              1 - (epsilon / min(delta, 1 - x_position))) + x_position)

            argmax, max_value = get_max_ks(random_values)
            vn_argmax, vn_max = get_max_vn(random_values)
            ks_statistic = max_value
            vn_statistic = vn_max
            ln_statistic = max_value / sqrt(argmax * (1 - argmax))

            if ks_statistic > ks_critical_value:  # if test dismisses H_0
                res_ks[i] += 1 / m
            if vn_statistic > vn_critical_value:  # if test dismisses H_0
                res_vn[i] += 1 / m
            if ln_statistic > ln_critical_value:  # if test dismisses H_0
                res_ln[i] += 1 / m
    return epsilons, res_ks, res_vn, res_ln


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # some code
    epsis, ks, vn, ln = monte_carlo(n, m, alpha, epsilon_max, delta, aufloesung, fehlerposition)
    # some other code
```

Any idea, how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened an issue on the [numba github page](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/5547) for this question. The problem was that numba could not determine the type of the list `random_values`.
The solution for this is to use a typed list as follows:

`random_values = typed.List.empty_list(types.float64)`.